# Solving system of equations which involve 'remainder's

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

How can I solve the following system of equations in the easiest way possible?

- m%14=p
- m%7=q
- p=q+7

**Note:** % denotes remainder of a division operation.

Comment: What denotes m%14=p?

Comment: Is it $$\frac{14}{100}m=p$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, `if we divide m by 14, the remainder would be p`.

Comment: Your notation seems a bit unclear.  Are you saying that $m=p+14k$ for some integer $k$, for example?

Comment: @lulu, Yes, you are correct.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{m}{14}=p$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, No. % is a remainder symbol.

Comment: But there are lots of solutions to your system.  For instance, to use more standard notation, $m\equiv 8 \pmod {14}$ and so on.  All you need is that $p\in \{7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$.

Comment: To clarify:  My understanding of the notation is that $0≤p≤13,0≤q≤6$, yes?

Comment: @lulu, This is actually a GRE quantitative problem. There are multiple answers given. Someone has to pick the correct answer or answers.

Comment: Ok, well what are the options?  Do you understand what my "solution" means?

Comment: @lulu, Page.25, Problem#5,   ...  https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf

Comment: Exactly,  So you just need to find one of those that gives a remainder in $\{7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ on division by $14$.

Comment: To elaborate:  $m=43$ fails, because $43\equiv 3\pmod {14}$ and $43\equiv 3\pmod 7$.  here we have $p=q=3$ so $p\neq q+7$.  Now work all of the others.

Answer (score 0):

So, if we have $$m=p+14k_1,m=q+7k_2$$ so nwe get $$p-q=7k_2-14k_1$$
$$7=7k_2-14k_1$$
This can be written as $$1=k_2-2k_1$$ If $k_1,k_2$ are integers, then we can solve this Diophantine equation.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, lulu